# WMI Performance Adapter function for Chrome browser?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, networking, port

Does someone know why the WMI Performance Adapter (WmiApSrv.exe) always starts when launching Chrome browser? Whats the function of this service?

I have heared this service can be maliciously used to "communicate" through the internet via open ports?

When I forcefully end this process in the taskmanager, Chrome keeps running perfectly, without issues.

Could it be that this WMI process is needed because one of Chrome's features called "Conceal local IP addresses with mDNS hostnames"?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are after. According to docs, the service has a startup type of Manual. So when chrome starts up, and wants to sample WMI performance counters, it makes sense that the executable will start at this time. Stopping the service only makes WMI performance counters unavailable, nothing impactful, so Chrome runs OK without it.

Comment: @WilliamClements , thanks! and what is this "WMI performance counters" doing in practical terms? Has it privacy related/computer identifying data? What can someone know when receiving this "counters" data, what's in it?

Comment: I don't mean to be flippant, but good documentation is found by googling "WMI performance counters" -- I will say the performance counters seem only to be about performance and not security. There could be a vulnerability exposed by the WMI performance counters API, but I know nothing about that.